# Mercurial/hg: get changes out of branch and into trunk

Tags: mercurial, merge

Apparently I've checked the last couple of week's commits into a branch. Apart from the changes to one file, I want to commit everything to the trunk. What do I do?

Comment: Would merging the branch into the trunk be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Matt - yes, I think it would be. I just did that, but I'm going to pay when I have to manually merge my config files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're talking *named branches* with Mercurial you're talking about a permanent attribute on a changeset.  A changeset cannot be on a different branch and still be the same changeset.    You can (as @Matt Ball) suggested merge that branch's result into default:

```
hg update default
hg merge thebranchname
```

Or you can go through, crazy, history-destroying contortions to pretend those changes weren't done on a branch (as @Rudi details (sorry)).

Just merge for now, and in the future consider using bookmarks, anonymous branches, or separate clones, for work you don't wnat to push immediately -- none of those make permanent annotations on changesets.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not push out any of the changesets of the new branch, and have no merges in the branch, you can use the mq extension to move the in trunk unwanted changeset to the tip of the branch.

```
$EDITOR ~/.hgrc
[extensions]
mq =
«save+quit»
# import all revisions up to the unwanted rev into a patch queue
hg qimport -r$BRANCH_TIP_REVISION:$IN_TRUNK_UNWANTED_REVISION

# edit the order of the patches, so that the unwanted patch is the last patch
$EDITOR .hg/patches/series
  «Move the in trunk unwanted patch to the last line of the file»
# Variant 1: don't change the branch
hg qpush -a    # apply all patches
hg qfinish -a  # finish all patches to regular hg changesets
hg log -l2     # find out the revision number of the latest revision you want in trunk
hg up -r trunk # checkout trunk
hg merge -r $LATEST_WANTED_REVISION_NUMBER # merge only the wanted changesets

# Variant 2: *All* patches are on the new branch, and
# you want only the differing changeset on the new branch
hg up -r trunk # move the working copy to trunk
hg qpush -a    # apply all patches
hg qpop        # unapply the unwanted one
hg qfinish     # finish the applied patches
hg branch $OLD_BRANCH_NAME # switch the working copy to the new branch
                           # if there is already another branch of this name,
                           # you need to checkout the other branch, apply the
                           # patch and merge trunk into that branch afterwards.
hg qpush       # apply the branch-specific patch
hg qfinish -a  # finish the patch
```

Comment: It's funny how solutions involving MQ invariably end up in a complicated, multi-step procedure :)

Comment: Since hg follows the principle "don't rewrite history, if it's not really necessary", hg deliberately doesn't make it particular easy to do. Rewriting history to reorder an arbitrary changeset involving branches is fairly major surgery.  Using MQ actually makes this process a lot less error-prone.